# Comparing strings in same series (row) but different columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I ran into this problem with comparing strings between two columns. What I want to do is to: For each row, check whether the string is column A is included in column B and if so, print a new string 'Yes' in column C.

Column A contains NaN values (blank cells in the csv I imported).

I have tried:

```
df['C']=df['B'].str.contains(df.loc['A'])
df.loc[df['A'].isin(df['B']), 'C']='Yes'
```

They both didn't work as I couldn't find the right way to compare strings.

Comment: 'df['C']=df['B'].str.contains(df.loc['A'])'
'df.loc[df['A'].isin(df['B']), 'C']='Yes'

edit: formating

Comment: Are you trying to notify us of your edit with this comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses list comprehension, so it may not be the fastest solution, but works and is concise.

```
df['C'] = pd.Series(['Yes' if a in b else 'No' for a,b in zip(df['A'],df['B'])])
```

EDIT: If you don't want to keep the values in C instead of overwriting them with 'No', you can do it like this:

```
df['C'] = pd.Series(['Yes' if a in b else c for a,b,c in zip(df['A'],df['B'], df['C'])])
```

Comment: Great answer!
What if I want only 'Yes' and leave others intact? I tried:
'Yes' for a,b in zip(df['A'], df['B']) if a in b
But it didn't work as expected

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['ab', 'abc'],
                   ['abc', 'ab']], columns=list('AB'))

df['C'] = np.where(df.apply(lambda x: x.A in x.B, axis=1), 'Yes', 'No')

df
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try regex: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html if you already made the code to id every cell or value have to work with.