# check if value in one cell is in another (same row)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a subset from a df of rows in which the string in column A (eg 'Player A') is included in the string in column B (eg 'Player A; Player B; Player C'), using the line:

```
df = df[df['A'].isin(df['B'])]
```

The problem with this is that the function isin() only works with list but the object (column B) in the function reflects all values in the series (column B). (Or so I think...)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing strings in same series (row) but different columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38709841/comparing-strings-in-same-series-row-but-different-columns)

Comment: Please provide an example DataFrame, what result you expect, and what result you are receiving from your code.